TS2339: Property 'scope' does not exist on type 'JwtPayload'
I'm encountering an error in IntelliJ when trying to use decodedJwt.scope.

The error message is: Property 'scope' does not exist on type 'JwtPayload'.
The only suggestions IntelliJ provides are: sub, aud, exp, iat, jti, iss, and nbf.

loadProfile(data: any) { 
    this.isAuthenticated = true;  
    this.accessToken = data['access-token']; 
    let decodedJwt = jwtDecode(this.accessToken);
    this.username = decodedJwt.sub; 
    this.roles = decodedJwt.scope;  
    window.localStorage.setItem("jwt-token", this.accessToken);
}

I've used decodedJwt.scope many times before without any issues, but now it suddenly doesn't seem to exist. Has anyone faced this issue before or knows how to resolve it?

I think that the latest version of the jwt-decode package doesn't have the scope property. I used version jwt-decode@^3.1.2, and it works.
<blink>
      loadProfile(data: any) {
        this.isAuthenticated=true;
        this.accessToken = data['access-token'];
        let decodedJwt: any =  jwtDecode(this.accessToken);
        this.username = decodedJwt.sub;
        this.roles = decodedJwt.scope;
        window.localStorage.setItem("jwt-token", this.accessToken);
    
      }
</blink>


There is no scope property in the JWTPayload class.
Based on the propose solution, you can construct a custom class (Auth0JwtPayload) containing the scope property. Then you should calling the jwtDecode by providing the type (Auth0JwtPayload).
interface Auth0JwtPayload extends JWTPayload {
  scope: string;
}

let decodedJwt: Auth0JwtPayload = jwtDecode<Auth0JwtPayload>(this.accessToken);

